# power problem with pi4 and 7" touchscreen

Tags: power, touchscreen, pi-4

I have a Pi4 that I have connected to a 7" touchscreen. The touchscreen is powered by a microUSB cable, the Pi4 is then powered through the GPIO, per the instructions. I keep getting the low power yellow lightning bolt.

Can I run the Pi4 off its own power supply through the USB-C port, and the touchscreen off its own MicroUSB port, after disconnecting the power supply to the GPIO? Or is there a better solution to fixing the low power signal?

Comment: You can run two separate power supplies. Just pull off the dupont wires.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can and should run the Pi from USB and also the 7" screen from USB. The lighting bolt indicates low power for (one of the) various reasons, but the one that got me the most (until I figured it out) was low quality USB cables. Do buy a very expensive one to supply the Pi, it is the way to go.